# save_post hook is not working after changing priority

Tags: plugins

I'm using calendar events pro plugin. In that plugin `save_post` hook is used and its priority set to 20.
I want to add some other data after processing calendar event's data.
So I did

```
add_action('save_post','save_tribe_func',30,2);
function save_tribe_func($post_id,$post){

#some data
}
```

But unfortunately I'm not able to add any data.

Here is the code which is in `save_tribe_func`

```
 function save_tribe_func($post_id,$post){
if($post->post_status == "publish" && $post->post_type == "tribe_events"){
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($post);
            unset($post->comment_count);
            unset($post->filter);
            //unset($post->ID);

            //print_r($post);
            //echo "<pre>";print_r(get_post_meta($post_id));

            $all_tags=get_the_terms($post_id,'tribe_event_tags');
            $all_cat=get_the_terms($post_id,'tribe_events_cat');
            $all_tag_arr=[];$index=0;
            foreach ($all_tags as $key => $each_tag) {
                $all_tag_arr[$index++] = $each_tag->term_id;
            }
            foreach ($all_cat as $key => $each_tag) {
                $all_tag_arr[$index++] = $each_tag->term_id;
            }
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($all_tags);
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($all_tag_arr);
            //exit();

            $author_user=get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $dept_site_url=$author_user->data->user_url;            

            $inputJSON=json_encode($post);

            //echo $inputJSON;
            $dept_site_url="http://192.168.200.69/wordpress_test/";
            $ch = curl_init($dept_site_url.'wp-json/myplugin/v1/posteventInsert/');
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);                                                                       
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $inputJSON);                                                                  
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
              'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                               
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($inputJSON))                                                                       
              );
            $last_post_id = curl_exec($ch);

            echo $last_post_id;

            $meta_url=$dept_site_url.'wp-json/myplugin/v1/postmetaInsert/';

            $post_meta=get_post_meta($post_id);
            // echo '<pre>';
            // echo 'get_save_events_data';
            // print_r($post_meta);
            // exit;
            if(isset($post_meta['_thumbnail_id'])){
                set_thumbnail_id($post_meta['_thumbnail_id'][0],$dept_site_url);
            }


          if($last_post_id != 0){

            //$post_meta=get_post_meta($post_id);

            $post_meta_arr=[];$i=0;
            foreach ($post_meta as $key => $metavalue) {
                $post_meta_arr[$i]['post_id']=$last_post_id;
                $post_meta_arr[$i]['meta_key']=$key;
                $post_meta_arr[$i]['meta_value']=$metavalue[0];         
                $i++;
            }
            $post_meta_arr[$i]['post_id']=$last_post_id;
            $post_meta_arr[$i]['meta_key']='event_main_site_id';
            $post_meta_arr[$i]['meta_value']=$post_id;
            $meta_url=$dept_site_url.'wp-json/myplugin/v1/posteventmetaInsert/';

            $post_all['meta']=$post_meta_arr;
            $post_all['tag']=$all_tag_arr;


            //echo "<pre>";print_r($post_all);


            $meta_json=json_encode($post_all);
            //echo $meta_json;

            //exit;
            $ch = curl_init($meta_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);                                                                       
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $meta_json);                                                                  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
                'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($meta_json))                                                                       
            );
            $meta_success = curl_exec($ch);
        }
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($post_meta_arr);
        //echo "id".$post_id;
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($post);


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the hook at its priority, then add your own at the same place. Use the code (as you seem to have) implicitly and all should go well. Without knowing where the hook is added, you'll want to check on that price as well (plugins_loaded, etc).

Comment: when I change this `add_action('save_post','save_tribe_func',30,2);` priority to 10 or even once I removed also and it's working but I need to execute this hook at priority 30. which I'm not able to do.

Comment: You can try to remove it at its priority and add yours later as well. Like O said I don't know where things happen in this plugin.

Comment: Check out https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action and add yours at the priority you wish. Make sure to use all `accepted_args`.

Comment: That solution is also not working :(

Comment: Bummer. It should work. Sorry.